# Php Error : failed to open stream: Permission denied in CentOS 7.1.1503(Core)

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I am running Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) build Aug 24 2015 18:11:25 on CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 64-bit. I am facing an issue while opening a file in 'w' mode and in 'a' mode also. I searched a lot for it. Tried all mentioned steps but still I am not getting desired result. The same file works and allows me to be opened in 'w' mode as well as in 'a' mode in my Windows 10. But it's not working in CentOS. There is file named '**home.php**' in the directory '**/var/www/html/editable**'. When I try to open that file from the file **srvr_file_access.php** in 'w' mode or 'a' mode, I get the following error:

> PHP Warning:  fopen(/var/www/html/editable/home.php): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/srvr_file_access.php

I have changed the owner and group of that file and directory to '**apache**' and have assigned **permission 755**. The permission for '**home.php**' file and directory are as follow :

**home.php**

```
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 apache apache 0 Oct 11 14:41 home.php
```

**/var/www/html/editable**

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 apache apache   21 Oct 11 14:56 editable
```

Please can anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried with 777 permissions ? does it work ?

Comment: Yeah. I tried that also. But still it is not working. @Pedro Lobito

Comment: Just `chmod` the file you want to write into using 777 permission like - `chmod 777 outputfile` try with `sudo` if it gives a permission error. :-)

Comment: are you sure the user apache should be the owner of the file / dir? if you upload your files to the server via FTP, which user credentials do you pass it?

Comment: It is also not working @Gourab Nag

Comment: Currently I have not configured any FTP related options. @GrafiCode Studio

Comment: I could suggest you to edit the sudoers file to gain access over everything in your machine, but i would recommend that only if you are really desperate.

Reference here for more info - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos or just google it

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that still have this problem, i solved it by creating the folder in /var then use chown apache:apache folder_name, and then move in www folder.

Answer (score 0):

cd [laravelfolder]

chmod 777 storage -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t storage -R

chmod 777 bootstrap
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t bootstrap -R